# GZipStream in an WebHttpResponse producing no data

Tags: c#, .net, http, gzip

I want to compress my HTTP Responses for client that supports it. I'm using [C# Webserver](http://webserver.codeplex.com/).

Here is the code used to send a standard response:

```
IHttpClientContext context = (IHttpClientContext)sender;
IHttpRequest request = e.Request;

string responseBody = "This is some random text";

IHttpResponse response = request.CreateResponse(context);

using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(response.Body))
{
    writer.WriteLine(responseBody);
    writer.Flush();
    response.Send();
}
```

The code above works fine. Now I added **gzip** support below. When I test it with a browser that supports gzip or a custom method, it returns an empty string. I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but I just can't find it...

```
IHttpClientContext context = (IHttpClientContext)sender;
IHttpRequest request = e.Request;

string acceptEncoding = request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"];
string responseBody = "This is some random text";

IHttpResponse response = request.CreateResponse(context);

if (acceptEncoding != null && acceptEncoding.Contains("gzip"))
{
    byte[] bytes = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(responseBody);
    response.AddHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");

    using (GZipStream writer = new GZipStream(response.Body, CompressionMode.Compress))
    {
         writer.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
         writer.Flush();
         response.Send();
    }
 }

 else
 {
     using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(response.Body))
     {
           writer.WriteLine(responseBody);
           writer.Flush();
           response.Send();
      }
 }
```

Comment: What is the webserver you are using? I don't recognise the interfaces you are using.

Comment: I'm sorry, I updated my question. It's C# Webserver : http://webserver.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pierre, pierre, pierre....

Your code can't work as expected.

`GZipStream` **must be closed before you read from the underlying stream**. Because `GZipStream` write the mandatory gzip footer in `GZipStream.Dispose`.

The following code will work:

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
     using (GZipStream gZipStream = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionMode.Compress))
     gZipStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

     byte[] compressed = stream.ToArray();
     response.Body.Write(compressed, 0, compressed.Length);

     response.Send();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm wrong, but don't you need a Content-Transfer-Encoding header? Doesn't WebResponse provide this internally?

Answer (score 0):

try to add

```
response.Filter = new GZipStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
```

Answer (score 0):

In a related situation with WebForms I ended up:

- Not using .NET's build-in GZip but the [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) library from codeplex. Transition was easy as it mimics the built-in GZip classes.
- Writing the zipped data to a MemoryStream first and only then re-write it to the Response stream.

I did not, however, target webbrowsers with that: I was  only interested in sending zipped data for a performance test over http.

If the issue lies withing the zipping part of your problem, maybe this will help you.